# php auto fill from mysql results

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I seem to be having an issue with array_fill().

I have a MYSQL table that has

```
------------------------
id - username - tickets
01   BOB        14
02   JIM        22
03   KYLE        9

-----------------------
```

I'm trying to save the values to an array, and 
for each ticket the user has, the username is added to the array...

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM table") or die (MySQL_error());

while($r = $select->fetch()){

$tickets_array = array_fill(0, $r['tickets'], $r['username']);

}
```

After this I am trying to push the values in $tickets_array to a javascript
array.

```
var tickets = new Array();

    <?php foreach($tickets_array as $key => $val){ ?>

    tickets.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');                    

    <?php } ?>
```

The code is working. However, I am only getting the first result from the database. tickets = 'BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB','BOB'

the other results are not being pushed to the javascript array for some reason.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong, and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are using array_fill, I would use fetch_all()

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

```
$select=$conn->query("SELECT * FROM table") or die (MySQL_error());

$tickets_array = $select->fetch_all());
```

Comment: I am using array_fill() because the username is added to the array based on how many tickets the user has.

Answer (score 0):

I would try this approach. Much simpler and it populates your array the way you want.

```
$tickets = array();

while($r = $select->fetch_object()) {
    for($i = 1; $i <= $r->tickets; $i++) {
        $tickets[] = $r->username;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not just adding the names from the database to an array. I am adding the names as tickets to an array based on the amount of tickets the user has in the database tickets column. e.g. KYLE has 9 tickets, so the username KYLE is added to the $tickets_array 9 times...  and the same for all other names. The end result is one HUGE array of names.

Comment: @JohnDoe, oh okay. I've updated it based on your explanation.

Comment: thanks for the help... but I am still having the same issue.

Comment: @JohnDoe try changing your foreach for the JS rendering to this: `foreach($tickets as $val)`. There are no specific keys specified. Additionally, also look at your database and see that it is populated.